Player A and B flip a coin alternatively till HT comes up. Whoever flips the T wins. What is the probability that A wins if they start?
I am confused why my approach is incorrect. The correct answer is 4/9.
We have that $P(A) = 1/2P(A|T) + 1/2P(A|H)$. Now we see by symmetry that $$P(A|T) = P(B) = 1 - P(A).$$ And we have that $$P(A|H) = 1/2(1/2\times 0 + 1/2P(A|HH)) = 1/2(1/2(1/2\times 1 + 1/2P(A|HHH)).$$
Here we see that $P(A|HHH) = P(A|H)$. So,
P(A|H) = 1/8 + 1/8P(A|H) which solving gives us $P(A|H) = 1/7$. But I am incorrect here as the correct answer is $P(A|H) = 1/3$.
Can someone explain the error in my logic?

Difficult to critique.  Please explain your thinking, slowly and carefully, of the following equation: $$P(A|H) = 1/2(1/2\times 0 + 1/2P(A|HH)) = 1/2(1/2(1/2\times 1 + 1/2P(A|HHH)).$$  Please do not leave an explanatory comment.  Instead, edit your posted question to carefully explain your thinking.

Your first expansion of $P(A|H)$ has an extra $1/2$ factor.

It is difficult to assess why you defined:
$$P(A|H) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{2} \times 0 + \frac{1}{2} P(A|HH) \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{2} \times 1 + \frac{1}{2} P(A|HHH) \right) \right)$$
Additional comments on this could help identify the problem.
To get to the correct answer, I suggest the following approach. Let us define $P(T)$ as the probability of winning this game if it is your turn to flip the coin and the last flip of your opponent resulted in tails, and $P(H)$ as the probability of winning the game if it is your turn to flip the coin and the last flip of your opponent resulted in heads. We find:
$$P(H) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} (1 - P(H)) \iff P(H) = \frac{2}{3}$$
This is because you either throw tails and win the game, or return heads to the opponent and thus have a probability of $1 - P(H)$ of winning.
We also find that:
$$P(T) = \frac{1}{2} (1 - P(H)) + \frac{1}{2} (1 - P(T)) \iff P(T) = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} P(T) \iff P(T) = \frac{4}{9}$$
This is because the game cannot finish immediately, and we thus return either heads or tails to our opponent.
Since player $A$ starts the game, the player finds themself in the latter scenario. Thus, the probability $P(A)$ of the player winning the game equals:
$$P(A) = P(T) = \frac{4}{9}$$

You may find it simpler to use $a_0,b_0$ to denote starting with no useful throw on their turn and $a_1,b_1$ to denote on the verge of success (ie an H has been tossed by opponent, and you just need to toss a T). And since we want to compute P(A wins), we curb B from winning. then we get the equations
$a_0=\frac12b_1+\frac12b_0 \tag1$
$b_0=\frac12a_1+\frac12a_0 \tag2$
$a_1 = \frac12\cdot1 + \frac12b_1 \tag3$
$b_1 = \frac12\cdot0 + \frac12a_1 \tag4$
Since A starts, we want to find $a_0$, and solving the system of linear equations, we get $a_0= \frac49$
